# Отследить изменение файла java

Tags: java, c++, файлы, консоль

Нужно отследить изменение файла, проект на java, при сборке использую maven.

Написал такой код:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycompany.mnvpro;


import aQute.libg.tarjan.Tarjan.Node;
import com.google.inject.spi.Element;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import static java.lang.Character.UnicodeBlock.of;
import java.util.Date;
import static javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.xml;
import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser;
import org.apache.tika.parser.Parser;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class Main {
      
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException, ParserConfigurationException, XPathExpressionException{
        
//Считывание xml файла

    //Объект файла config.xml
    File configFile = new File("D:\\java\\config.xml");     
    String[] Path = readConfig(configFile);
    
//То что мы получили из config.xml
    System.out.println("Входной путь: "+ Path[0]);
    System.out.println("Выходной путь: "+ Path[1]);
    
//Следить за изменением файла  config.xml---------------------------------------
    
    long millisec = configFile.lastModified();
    
    // date and time
    Date oldMod = new Date(millisec);
    
    System.out.println("Время последнего изменения: " + oldMod);
    
    boolean isCheck = true;
    
    int i = 0;
    
//Проверка на изменение---------------------------------------------------------
    while(isCheck){
    
        long milliSecCur = configFile.lastModified();
        
        // date and time
        Date CurMod = new Date(milliSecCur);
    
        System.out.println("Время текущего изменения: " + CurMod);
    
        //System.out.println(oldMod);
        //System.out.println(CurMod);
        
        
        boolean isMod = (milliSecCur == millisec);
        
        boolean isModBig = (milliSecCur > millisec);
        
        // Если текущее не равно старому
        // Значит файл был изменен
        if(isMod == false){ 
        
            i++;
            
            //Наш файл был изменен
            System.out.println("Config.xml has been changed");
            
            //Изменить объект с новым Modified
            File NewConfig = new File("D:\\java\\config.xml");
            
            //Опять просматривать файл
            Path = readConfig(NewConfig);
    
            //То что мы получили из config.xml
            System.out.println("Входной путь: "+ Path[0]);
            System.out.println("Выходной путь: "+ Path[1]);
            
            millisec = milliSecCur;
    
            if(i == 3){ // Ждать 3 изменения файла
              
                break;
            
            }
        
        } //if
        
        //Наш файл был изменен
        System.out.println("Ждать изменений");
    
    }//while

    //Точка выхода из цикла
    System.out.println("Мы вышли из цикла");
    
}//main

    static String[] readConfig(File NewConfig) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        
    //Массив для входного и выходного пути    
    String[] str = new String[2];    
        
    if(NewConfig.exists()){ //Есть ли такой файл
    
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(NewConfig); //Reader для чтения файла
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader); // Буфер памяти
                
    String line; //Строчка из файла
        
    String newInputDir = ""; //Новый входной путь
    String newOutputDir = ""; //Новый выходной путь
        
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { // Пока не закончился config.xml 
    
        //System.out.println(line); //Показать какая сейчас строчка активна
   
        boolean isIn = line.contains("<Input_dir>"); 
        boolean isOut = line.contains("<Output_dir>");
    
        if(isIn){ //Это секция <Input_dir>?
        
            newInputDir = line.replace("<Input_dir>", "");
            newInputDir = newInputDir.replace("</Input_dir>", "");
            
            boolean isSt = newInputDir.startsWith(" "); //Начинается ли на " "
            
            while(isSt){
            
                newInputDir = newInputDir.replace(" ", "");
                isSt = newInputDir.startsWith(" ");
            }
            
            str[0] = newInputDir; //Результат: входной путь
   
        }
        else if(isOut){ //Это секция <Output_dir>?
        
            newOutputDir = line.replace("<Output_dir>", "");
            newOutputDir = newOutputDir.replace("</Output_dir>", "");
            
            boolean isStart = newOutputDir.startsWith(" "); //Начинается ли на " "
            
            while(isStart){
            
                newOutputDir = newOutputDir.replace(" ", "");
                isStart = newOutputDir.startsWith(" ");
            }
            
            str[1] = newOutputDir; //Результат: выходной путь
            
        }
        
    }
    
    //Мои директории
    //System.out.println(newInputDir); 
    //System.out.println(newOutputDir); 
       
    }
    else{ //Если config.xml нет, то будем его ждать 
    
        System.out.println("Config.xml has't found"); 
          
    } 
        
        //Вернуть массив: входной и выходной путь
        return str;     
    }
    
}
```

Идея такая: запускаю этот проект из консоли. Эта программа считывает из файла данные и дальше отслеживает изменения в цикле. В процессе работы программы в консоле, я открываю файл в ворде, меняю данные в файле, пересохраняю файл, чтобы он был изменен, и вылетает предупреждение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее я закрываю это окно, все равно нажимаю на крестик, и сохраняю файл, в таком случае имею такой ошибку в консоле:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как можно обыграть эту ситуацию, чтобы я мог проверять изменение файла через программу на java, например отслеживая результат через консоль. При этом, когда работает программа на java, я могу изменить этот файл и пересохранить, чтобы логика, которая описывается выше выполнялась. У кого-какие идеи, подскажите, что можно придумать, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Погугли либы. Или попинай винапи.

Comment: Точно не знаю, но предполагаю, что при сохранении файла т.к. у вас еще файл открыт, то вызывается функция `readConfig`, где вы пытаетесь еще раз открыть файл. Попробуйте вызывать функцию `readConfig` после того, как файл будет закрыт. Например держать в `boolean` закрыт ли файл и если он будет закрыт, то уже вызывать функцию. [Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390592/check-if-file-is-already-open) есть пример проверки закрыт ли файл.

Comment: А причем здесь метка с++?

Answer (score 0):

Объекты:

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(NewConfig); //Reader для чтения файла
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader); // Буфер памяти
```

после использования надо закрывать:

```
reader.close();
br.close();
```

Comment: Да вроде не обязательно: [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388602/do-i-need-to-close-both-filereader-and-bufferedreader)

Comment: Не понимаю почему ответ заминусили, если не используется конструкция try(Ваш ридер) (которая гарантирует, что в случае чего, поток будет закрыт) то потоки обязательно надо закрывать руками. Если автор хочет отслеживать, то ему придётся обращаться к файлу постоянно закрывая/открывая поток.К тому же, не мешало бы, делать это в отдельном thread 
и хоть иногда усыплять его.